# Assemble/combine images with overlapping in R

Tags: r, image-processing, overlap

I have in a folder a large number of small images 64x64 pixels. I load all of these image in a list.

```
setwd("C:/Users/PC/Pictures/")
jpeg <- list.files(folder)
```

I would like to merge/assemble all these images to create one large. I would like to paste the image N+1 on the previous image N with a gap of 8 pixels, from image 1 to k. So the image N+1 will cover partially the previous image N. How to do it? [image]

Comment: The gap is 8 pixels in this case. So the image N+1 is located on the 9th pixels.

Comment: I wrote and then deleted an answer using the `EBImage` package because it has very nice `combine` and `tile` features, but it didn't let me control the overlap the way I was hoping and thinking. In case it helps, here is the code from my deleted answer https://pastebin.com/XEM10PYA  The package author uses  StackOverflow... let's see if we can get his attention... @aoles can you help?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to paste an image in another one ? probably can use after the function imshift from imager package

Comment: Sure. That sounds promising but it is too late in my time zone for me to continue. I will give it a try in the morning and @aoles should also be online by then

Comment: Do you think I should go through matrix. Mean, I change each 64x64 pixels image into a matrix and paste them into a large matrix with each time a gap of 8 pixels.

Comment: Laurent, are you still interested in this problem? If so, a little more information may help. Specifically, how do you want to "blend" the image? Is each successive image to overwrite the previous where they overlap as your example shows? Or do you want the images to blend in some manner? `EBImage` is a good approach even if the images are treated as matrices. The engine behind `EBImage` is **very** efficient with matrices.